# json converting to array swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I get json like this from the server:

```
array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'Radni nalog 1', 'threadTypeList' => array(
            array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'Crvena'), 
            array('id' => '2', 'name' => 'Plava'), 
            array('id' => '3', 'name' => 'Zelena'), 
            array('id' => '4', 'name' => 'Žuta'), 
        ), 'token' => 'xxuoE73VKwyKk1KmGTy26P72cgsuneMzNOes');
```

How can I convert this json to the dictionary. Here is my function for conversion, but it is totally wrong and I am stuck with it.

```
func convertStringToDictionary2(text: String) -> [AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? [AnyObject]
            return json
        } catch {
            print("Something went wrong")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

and when I try to get data like this:

```
    let result = convertStringToDictionary(jsonString as String)

//creating array of objects threadType and populating threadTypeList property
let resultThreadList = (result?["threadTypeList"] as! String)

let new = convertStringToDictionary2(resultThreadList as String)
```

I get an error: Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x10f20dd88) to 'NSString' (0x10df90c40).

I am able to get all the variables from json except ** threadTypeList** which is an array of arrays.

Comment: why are you converting resultThreadList as String ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x10f20dd88) to 'NSString' (0x10df90c40)

means:

*The object you are going to access is **`Array`** but you want to get a **`String`** which is impossible*.

```
let resultThreadList = result?["threadTypeList"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
```

---

`resultThreadList` implies an array as well as the PHP type `'threadTypeList' => array(` but consider that a PHP (associative) *array* `array('id' => '1'` is actually a dictionary.